# How to apply material design lite to asp .net form buttons?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, material-design, material-design-lite

This question is not duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790302/how-to-apply-google-material-design-to-asp-net-controls-i-e-checkbox-button-a). I am trying to materialize the button (ASP.NET web form control). Button is materialized but unable to get ripple effect. Actually this works for normal button (HTML control).

**HTML Snippet**

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
  Button
</button>
```

This works perfectly with ripple effect.

**ASP.Net Snippet**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="button" CssClass="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent"/>
```

This is not working as expected.
I was searching this issue and finally got [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790302/how-to-apply-google-material-design-to-asp-net-controls-i-e-checkbox-button-a). Anyways I cant solve the issue. The problem is I cant get ripple effect for asp.net controlled button. IS there any way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to use a pur html button. After it depends what button do. But you can trigge hidden asp.net button in javascript from the html button.

Comment: <asp:Button> does not create <button> tag but <input> tag

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque please ellaborate..

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque So you actual point is to use html button and trigger it by  runtat="server" attribute so that it will work as asp.net button

Comment: You can refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187482/how-can-i-use-the-button-tag-with-asp-net

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque thanks..now got an idea...